# integrate conditional expectation with respect to conditional term

Tags: probability

I have an equation $\int^a_0 \mathbb{E}[Y|X,V=s]\,ds$, will it be the same as $ \mathbb{E}[Y|X,V\le a]$. If not, what will be the answer to the integration?

Comment: A clear counterexample is when $\mathbb P(V<0)>0$.